# Selecting the latest date time from different date time fields

Tags: mysql

There are different date time fields in different tables and I have to select the latest of all the date time fields. The tables are:

```
Question
--------
askedby
questionType
lastupdated

Document
----------
submittedBy
documentType
lastupdated

Instruction
-----------
submittedBy
instructionType
lastupdated
```

Tried to start with

```
SELECT Question.lastupdated,Document.lastupdated,Instruction.lastupdated
FROM Question,Document,Instruction
WHERE lastupdated=(select max(lastupdated))
ORDER BY lastupdated DESC
```

If the values for lastupdated in the tables are:

```
Question table:    2015-06-28 07:00:00
Document table:    2015-06-28 07:30:00
Instruction table: 2015-06-28 08:00:00
```

Then the value from the `Instruction` table should be selected, like `2015-06-28 08:00:00`

Here I have to select the latest of lastupdated column from three databases. I am new to SQL queries, not sure how to start with.

Comment: What did you try so far ?

Comment: What result would you expect? Can edit the question and add a sample expected output?

Comment: Sorry for not being clear with my question.

Comment: It's still not all clear to me what the output should be, do you just want the date or do you need anything else?

Comment: Just need the lastupdated datetime field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it looks like you only want to pull the last date from three disjunct sets a simple option would to use a query for each table and use `union all` to make one set out of the three results and apply max to that set, like this:

```
SELECT MAX(lastupdated) AS max_lastupdated
FROM 
(
    SELECT MAX(lastupdated) lastupdated FROM Question
    UNION ALL
    SELECT MAX(lastupdated) lastupdated FROM Document
    UNION ALL
    SELECT MAX(lastupdated) lastupdated FROM Instruction
) A
```

Actually you don't even need to choose the max value in the three select statements, just getting the lastupdated should be enough, although the query above might be faster if backed by an index:

```
SELECT MAX(lastupdated) AS max_lastupdated
FROM 
(
    SELECT lastupdated FROM Question
    UNION ALL
    SELECT lastupdated FROM Document
    UNION ALL
    SELECT lastupdated FROM Instruction
) A
```

[Sample SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fdfeb/1)

Comment: @trx It's the alias/name given to the result from the derived table (the result of the queries inside the parenthesis).